# Анализ большого объема данных (несколько миллионов полей в БД)

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Имеется база данных MySQL, в ней содержится таблица, которая имеет несколько миллионов записей. В данной таблице есть поля, по которым необходимо осуществлять поиск. Пример задачи (запроса): по выбранной дате (скажем за два месяца) необходимо получить количество товара определенного магазина по его ID (id - это название магазина, не первичный ключ), после чего я получаю массив объектов из миллиона записей.

Я использую ORM Eloquent и в результате получаю объект. Получаю его как минимум за 10 секунд, после чего данные необходимо ещё и обработать (вывести показатели определенного магазина или магазинов за каждый месяц указанного периода), это может быть "прибыль" или "убытки" магазина, которые мне необходимо подсчитать из пары сотен тысяч строк. Есть ли более оптимальные способы подобных запросов или их обработки? Подобные запросы занимают не менее 10 секунд, а если говорить про выборку нескольких магазинов за большее число времени, то можно прождать и пару минут.

Comment: сложные запросы, те уже несущие часть обработки. либо частичные запросы и хранение данных в редисе

Comment: несколько миллионов записей это очень мало записей для базы данных и запросы должны отрабатывать очень быстро. По выбираемым значениям добавлены индексы на колонки? есть ли проблема n+1 при использовании orm? Добавьте пример медленного sql запроса который уходит в БД

Comment: надо смотреть насколько оптимально вы используете индексы для поиска, и насколько можно перенести обработку данных с пхп на саму базу. несколько миллионов строк, это в целом не так уж много. Если оптимизировать работу данными средствами нельзя, то надо хранить какие-то промежуточные данные в отдельных таблицах и по мере надобности их пресчитывать. Так что пока что тут разговор ни о чем, давайте сюда стрктуру таблицы, пример данных в ней, запрос который вы выполняете, сколько строк он возвращает в среднем и вы их передаете на пхп. Что вы с этим делаете на пхп, и какой результат получаете.

Comment: А то получится вдруг, что вы на клиент предаете 100тыс строк, а потом после обработки получаете 20 строк, в итоге самое долгое это передача данных из базы в пхп. Ну и explain запросов, конечно.

Comment: @teran Смотрите, я получаю все объекты по выбранным фильтрам (магазин, дата и ещё пара фильтров), получаю по этим фильтрам массив объектов и из этого массива объектов мне нужно собрать массив, в массиве суб-массивы в датой (год-месяц-день), в массиве с датой лежат некоторые данные, такие как выручка магазина, объем экспорта и импорта товара, тип товара (тип товара - это ID, по которому берется сам товар из другой таблицы). Соответственно и сам запрос к БД занимает много времени и работа цикла PHP, которые всё подсчитывает и кладет нужные данные в нужный месяц.

Comment: давайте конкретику. по структуре и данным как написано выше. прям синтаксис `create table` с запросом, с экплейном. чего и сколько возвращает, и как долго выбирает.

Comment: Структура (type, date, price, amount, name, psc) где тип - это покупка/продажа, дата - это дата, прайс - стоимость, количество, название и шт). Выборка из Laravel Eloquent с различными фильтрами (пример SQL запроса: "select * from `data` where (`code` LIKE [ID маганизна] and (`time` >= 2020-12-0 and `time` <= 2021-12-0))" Данная выборка показывает данные магазина по его ID за год, могут быть и другие фильтры (не полный оборот, а лишь закупки/продажи и т.д)

Comment: неужели третий раз написать надо, чтобы вы написали нормальный create table с индексами, и примеры запросов, прям вот как есть, а не вот это вот?

Comment: В комментариях я к сожалению не могу написать всю структуру, так как не хватает символов, которые могу написать.

CREATE TABLE `data` (
  `type` varchar(4) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` date NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `code` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `unit` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,

Comment: `price` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `weight` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `region` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

Comment: При запросе ```"select * from `data` where ((`time` >= 2021-10-0 and `time` <= 2021-12-0))"``` я получаю почти два миллиона записей за 11 секунд, после их обработки на стороне PHP время выполнения занимает около 20 секунд - это на локальном, довольно хорошем железе. На сервере SQL запрос может составлять 30 - 40 секунд.

Comment: отредактируйте вопрос, добавьте туда данные на создание таблицы, выполняемый запрос и приложите результат вывода ```"explain select * from `data` where ((`time` >= 2021-10-0 and `time` <= 2021-12-0))"```